# = での比較がうまくいかない

Tags: java

以前の質問の意図を簡略化するために改めて書いたコードですTimerTaskを使い制御するのでbreakなどの制御文は使えないです。何故Lをfalseにしてるのに終わらないのですか？

```
public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        boolean K = true;
        boolean L = true;

        while(and(K,L)){
            System.out.println("test");
            L = false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean and(boolean a, boolean b){
        if(a = true){
            if(b = true){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

`=`だと代入になります。比較演算子の `==` を使うと動くはずです。

```
if(a == true){
```

もしくは、

```
if(a){
```

だけでもいいですね。

Comment: ありがとうございました。

Comment: @ミント 問題が解決した場合には、その回答を承認しましょう。(チェックボタンを押す)

Answer (score 2):

Javaに限らず、殆どのプログラミング言語での　=　は代入です。
あなたのコードは　aの値をtrueにしてからaの中身を見てif判定　していることになります。
（bも同じです）

```
if(a = true){//判定結果は絶対にtrueにしかならない
    // aは絶対true（当たり前）
    if(b = true){//判定結果は絶対にtrueにしかならない
    //bは絶対にtrue（当たり前）
        return true;
    } else {
    //　ここでもbは絶対にtrue
    }
} else {
// ここでもaは絶対true
}



//正しい例
if(a == true){
    if(b == true){
        return true;
    }
}
```

要するに、あなたの書いたコードは分解すると下になります

```
a = true;
if (a == true) {
    b = true;
    if (b == true) {
    }
}
```

Comment: VisualBasicなどでは比較にも=を使いますね。

Comment: 文脈に依存して`=`の意味が代入にも比較にもなる言語(VBもたしかそう)や、違う意味で記号を使っている言語(Pascalだと`:=`が代入で`=`は比較)もありますので「プログラミング言語での`=`は代入」とは言えません。(Cでは`=`は代入で、Cとその文法を参考にした言語の普及度が高いので`=`が代入を意味することが多い、のは事実です)

Comment: ありがとうございます
修正しておきました